TS-520S Transmit Issue
I'm new to amateur radio. I've just passed my foundation exam (UK) which allows me to transmit at 25W.
I inherited my dad's Kenwood TS-520S and have an AT-200 and have been following this procedure to prepare to transmit: QSL.net TS-520 Tune-up Procedure
I can get through steps 1 to 11 and see the power into my dummy load on the AT-200 while in tune or CW mode. As soon as I switch to USB or LSB, the power meter on the AT-200 has no movement. Is it possible that the transmitter is faulty?

Does the power/ALC meter on TS520 move when you talk to the mic? If no, did you adjust the mic gain and carrier level knobs?

USB and LSB are single sideband modes with a suppressed carrier. This is an advantage of SSB signals: all the power is used to transmit your audio.
In practice, this means that unless there is something going into the microphone / audio input, you won't see any power going out to the antenna. Some hams whistle into the microphone to generate a signal.

I'm starting to suspect a faulty microphone in this case, thanks.
